# /admin path display login box along with access denied message (drupal 7)

Tags: 7, users

In drupal 6 when visiting /admin, an access denied message was shown in the admin theme along with a login box. How can I do the same in drupal 7? Currently the regular theme is shown along with an access denied message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [Login Toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module, which show the login block on the *Access denied* pages and
give the *View the administration theme* permission to anonymous users.

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal login system in an external module by offering the following features and usability improvements:
>
> 1. Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.
> 2. Allow users to login immediately.
>    Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
> 3. The module provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log in". The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to their original page upon login.